# will Kali linux GRUB make changes to MBR on windows OS

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, grub, mbr

I am new to Kali Linux and am trying to install it in a Virtual Box on my windows 7 system.  My question is will Kali linux GRUB make changes to the 'Actual' MBR on Windows OS when I am installing Kali in the Virtual Box.

The entire idea is to make the Virtual Box version of my Kali Linux bootable (in the Virtual Box)

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, VirtualBox is a virtual environment simulator.

So it will act like a container, providing necessary components required by the guest OS (in this case, Kali Linux), but also sandboxing it completely so that it does not disrupt the functioning of the Host environment (windows).

I believe you can go ahead, GRUB won't destroy anything outside from within VirtualBox.